# Orbeon's 4.5 navigation to success page does not work in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, orbeon

In my properties-local.xml there is:

```
<property
as="xs:string"
name="oxf.fr.detail.process.workflow-send.*.*"
value='
    require-uploads
    then validate-all
then save(draft="true")
then send("oxf.fr.detail.send.success")'
    />
<property as="xs:anyURI" name="oxf.fr.detail.send.success.uri.*.*"
          value="[Important WS URL]"/>
<!-- HTTP method to use to navigate to the success page -->
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.send.success.method.*.*" value="POST" replace="all"/>
```

After clicking Workflow-send button in Form Runner there is a request sent to my WS (which saves data to database, not important) and then I send `oxf.fr.detail.send.success` so there should be a navigation to my `Importnant WS` (HTTP Post). It works fine in all browsers expect Internet Explorer. In IE there is a dialog, which warns me about leaving the page ('You may loose some unsaved data: -> Leave the page -> Stay on the page'). No matter which option: staying/leaving I choose, there is no further action.

Any idea about a workaround?

---

**UPDATE**

In Orbeon 4.9 I've tried this:

```
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.detail.process.workflow-send.*.*">
    require-uploads
    then validate-all
    then send(
    uri = "[Important WS URL]",
    replace = "all",
    method = "POST",
    content = "xml"
    )
</property>
```

with the very same dialog showing up..

Comment: Could you try to reproduce this with 4.9? (If the issue has been fixed between 4.5 and 4.9, obviously, I'd recommend you to upgrade to 4.9.) If the issue happens in 4.9, could you attach a screenshot of that dialog to your question? Also, what version of IE are you seeing this on?

Comment: It's exactly this dialog: http://i.stack.imgur.com/aRik7.jpg. Unfortunately, it happens both on Orbeon 4.5 and Orbeon 4.9. I use Internet Explorer 11, the newest update.

Comment: OK, got it. But I wasn't able to reproduce this. I.e. I didn't get the dialog on IE11 with  4.9. And the code checks this, i.e. if you have a replace="all", then it doesn't show the dialog: https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/fr/process/FormRunnerActions.scala#L271. I'm not sure what is happening in your case. BTW, the replace="all" you have on that property is ignored; properties are just name/value pairs.

Comment: Well, so maybe that's the real issue here! So how would I make replace='all' not to be ignored?

Comment: I've updated my question giving example of property I used in Orbeon 4.9's properties-local (with no luck).

Comment: Well... I'm lost. Were you not saying that the target page was loaded, and that the problem was just the confirmation dialog on IE11? If that's the case, then the problem isn't that the replace="all" isn't understood. Things are working the way you want on Chrome, correct? This is still only a problem on IE11, or are you referring to another issue?

Comment: Also, feel free to send me an email (avernet@orbeon.com). I'd like to help, but I'm not sure we're making much progress here.